# Retrieve the rows which has matches for all the rows of another resultset in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The following are the tables of my application

> Product(product_id(pk),name,price)
>
> Customer(customer_id(pk),customer_name,address)
>
> Purchases(customer_id(fk),product_id(fk),quantity);

```
select count(product_id),customer_id from purchases 
where product_id in ( 
                     select product_id from product where price >200) 
group by customer_id
```

i'm able to do it up to here where the above query retrieves count of the products for each customer. i even tried the below one

```
select sub.customer_id from (select count(product_id) as prod_count,
customer_id from purchases where product_id in 
                                         ( select product_id from product where price >200) 
group by customer_id) as sub 
having sub.prod_count=(select count(product_id) from product where price>200);
```

Now how can i find the customers who purchased all the products with price above 200.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a coding service for your homework.

Comment: Please post the query you have tried so that it will be easy for people to help you.

Comment: i got it, my query is working the only mistake i have done is using select sub.customer_if from(...) in the start i corrected it as select sub.customer_id,sub.prod_count. i got the desired result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT customer_id
FROM (
       SELECT   PUR.customer_id, PUR.product_id
                FROM (SELECT product_id FROM Product WHERE price > 200 ) Pro_above_200 PRO
                INNER JOIN Purchases PUR
                ON PUR.product_id = PRO.product_id ) T 
GROUP BY customer_id, product_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM  Product WHERE price > 200 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct customer_id  from purchase
where customer_id not in 
(
 select customer_id 
 from(
   select purchases.customer_id , 
       case when Product.proce>200 then 1 else 0 end as price_gt_twh

   from purchases 
   left join Producton purchases.product_id =Product.product_id 
)data
WHERE price_gt_twh=0
)customers
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from customer join select * from product where product.price > 200.
```

I'm assuming you have the price column in your product table

What you need is a join statement